# Python Flask - how to run a web-visible server from a docker container (on a mac)?

Tags: python, docker, web-services, flask

I downloaded a pre-built docker container, it has a web server running on Python's Flask. The web service is visible on localhost, but **I want to access the web service from the web**.

I see a lot of similar questions, and all of them have some arcane answers. Some recommend using `nginx` or `gunicorn` as a web server. I don't know enough to route this pre-built container to some other container or network interface. Additionally, it appears that Mac has a smaller set of network operators than other OS.

**Does the code below properly expose a web service to the web on Mac?**

**Is it my router using some sort of sandboxed network rules to avoid devices on the network seeing each other?**

I see a recommendation to add `CMD ["python3", "-m", "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]` , but I don't know where

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

from com.my.server import app
             
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=False)
   # I tried to find my local ip:
   # app.run(host='192.168.0.2', port=8080, debug=False) # does not work


 In the console:

* Serving Flask app "com.my.server" (lazy loading)
* Environment: production

Debug mode: off
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (actually 127.0.0.1:8080)
```

Comment: does the docker image expose the port (in this case `8080`)? it could be useful if you share the docker file or docker compose.

Comment: @cspinetta I'm not really sure where to find the docker file. I got docker desktop, which shows my image, but I can not even find it on disk. I got docker files in a folder downloaded from github, but I have no indication that they actually affect the downloaded container :/

Comment: Here's the docker image: docker pull lukalabs/cakechat:latest